# Is there a way to have better buffer borders in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-sf

I'm hoping maybe someone can help me with the following situation.
I'm working on a project were I need to plot a circle (radius) around a centroid in R. I'm also using this centroid to do an intersection with other geometry. The problem I'm facing is that the buffer border is not a very well defined circle which doesn't look good when I plot both the circle and the intersection.

My code looks somewhat like this:

using sf and ggplot2

Radius of 100km
`circle = st_buffer(centroid,100000)`
and for the intersection

`intersection = st_intersection(geometry,circle)`

for the plot

`ggplot()+geom_sf(data= circle, fill = "yellow")`

[The border of buffer is "low quality"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlfx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so bad! That said, if you really want to smooth the circle/buffer border, you can use the package `smoothr`.

Here is one possibility :

```r
library(smoothr)

# Smooth circle border
circle_smooth <- smooth(densify(circle, max_distance = 10), method = "ksmooth")

# Plot
ggplot2::ggplot()+
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data= circle_smooth, fill = "yellow")
```

Comment: Please, let me know if the rendering is as you wish. Cheers.

Comment: Played around with the smoothness and it's much better now

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sf::st_buffer(..., nQuadSegs=)`

From https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/geometric-operations.html

> The third and final argument of st_buffer() is nQuadSegs, which means ‘number of segments per quadrant’ and is set by default to 30 (meaning circles created by buffers are composed of 4×30=120 lines). This argument rarely needs to be set. Unusual cases where it may be useful include when the memory consumed by the output of a buffer operation is a major concern (in which case it should be reduced) or when very high precision is needed (in which case it should be increased).

Answer (score 0):

I tried out different values for `nQuadSegs` in `sf::st_buffer(..., nQuadSegs=)` but somehow it seems that this does not change anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34144261)